# Correct icon size for Big Sur preference panels

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, macos-big-sur

When building my app for macOS Big Sur, and switching my preference panel toolbar style to `.preference`, the icons just don't seem to size correctly.

No matter if I use @1x/@2x PNG variants, or universal PDF vector images with a single scale, my icons always turn out larger and blurry compared to using a SF Symbol icon.

Now that my app needs to be backwards compatible with 10.13 I can't use symbol images.

Here is what my toolbar looks like

[image]

What is the correct way to get properly sized icons in a preference panel toolbar?

Do I need to include a margin in my vector assets? If so, what is the correct point size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector images don't seem to go well with `NSToolbar`. I created an `NSImage` extension for them to manually create a toolbar friendly image.

```
extension NSImage {

    convenience init?(namedVectorToolbarImage name: String) {
        guard let image = NSImage(named: name) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init()

        let small = image.resized(to: .init(width: 24, height: 24))
        let regular = image.resized(to: .init(width: 32, height: 32))
        let reps = regular.representations + small.representations

        isTemplate = true

        reps.forEach {
            addRepresentation($0)
        }
    }
```

The `resize()` method here is just another extension for producing a resized image. On top of that I set `NSToolbar.sizeMode` to small if the system is not (below) `macOS 11.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I got a good result with `26x26px` vector PDF. The icon size was `22x22px` with the margins but the icon was blurry. Enabling `Preserve Vector Data` option did the trick

You can set it under the `Image Set` settings:

[image: Image Set settings]

Comment: My images all had "Preserve Vector Data" on, doesn't help.